# Java. Парсинг html страницы

Tags: java, парсер

Есть [сайт](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=26716), внизу вкладка Drops, там табличка, в конце ее процент. Как его достать? Сама табличка в json, но процентов не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Используй либо библиотеку [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) или [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). Первая тебе поможет лазать по сайту и кликать по нему, так же забирая нужные данные, а вторая тебе просто разрешит распарсить html страницу, которую ты передаешь.

Comment: Пробовал Jsoup, она забирает в таком же виде как и к примеру
URL _url = new URL(url);
URLConnection spoof = _url.openConnection();
Или что-то делаю не так?

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url 

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
Получаешь документ, с него ты и начинаешь парсить. Находишь свою таблицу, которая тебе нужна, и у нее уже забираешь проценты

Comment: К сожалению это не катит, таблица генерится при открытии страницы

Comment: Ну используй тогда селениум. Подгрузи страницу, забери с нее данные, сохрани в html файл и распарси jsoup'ом.